# retrieve session value and connect to different db in logout function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to set the company name in a session and retrieve the same to connect to a different database, i am setting the session using $this->session->set_userdata($newdata); and retrieving the session using $companyName = $this->session->userdata['newdata']['company']; but somehow retrieval is not happening and i am unable to load the correct db for updating logout information i.e it simply does not update the pr_system_attendance table by connecting to a different db. I am getting the correct value if i echo $company; after $company = $row1->company; this is FYI

My model code is as follows:

```html
  function check_admin_login(){
   
   $this->db->where('username', trim($this->input->post('username')));
   $this->db->where('userpass ', sha1(trim($this->input->post('userpass'))));
   $this->db->where('status', '1');
   $this->db->where('deleted', '0');
   $this->db->select('*');
   $query = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users']);
   if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query->row();
    $this->db->where('userid', $row->id);
    $this->db->select('firstname,lastname,profileimage,company');
    $query1 = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users_details']);
    $row1 = $query1->row();
    $newdata = array(
         'is_admin_logged_in' => true,
         'admin_user_name' => $row->username,
         'admin_userpass' => $row->userpass,
         'admin_id'=>$row->id,
         'admin_lastlogin'=>date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$row->lastlogin),
         'admin_lastloginip'=>$row->lastloginip,
         'lastrefresh'=>time(),
         'company'=>$row1->company 
       );
       $company = $row1->company;
     $this->session->set_userdata($newdata); 
    $companyName = $this->session->userdata['newdata']['company'];
   
    $this->update_admin_login_time($this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
    $this->admin_init_elements->set_global_user($row->username,$row->userpass);
    if($this->input->post('remember'))
    {
     $cookie = array('name'   => 'username','value'  => $row->username,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
     $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
    $name = $row1->firstname.' '.$row1->lastname;
    $cookie1 = array('name'   => 'name','value'  => $name,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie1); 
    $cookie2 = array('name'   => 'image','value'  => $row1->profileimage,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie2); 
    
    
    return 'Login Successful';
   }else{
    return 'Incorrect Username or Password.';
   }
   
  }
  function logout()
  {
   global $USER;
   $companyName = $this->session->userdata['newdata']['company'];
  
   $otherdb = $this->load->database("$companyName", TRUE);

   $this->db->from("$companyName"."pr_users");
   $query1 = $this->db->query("Select * from pr_system_attendance where userid = '".$USER->id."' and DATE(`login_time`) = CURDATE()");
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
   if($query1->num_rows() > 0)
   {
    $row = $query1->row();
    
    $sql1 = "UPDATE pr_system_attendance set logout_time = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'  where userid = '".$USER->id."' and DATE(`login_time`) = CURDATE()";
    
    
    
    $query2 = $this->db->query($sql1);
    
    
   }
   $sql="UPDATE `".$this->myTables['users']."` SET 
     `if_online` = '0'
      WHERE `id` = '".$USER->id."'" ;
   $query=$this->db->query($sql); 
   
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get session data with below line of code

```
//$companyName = $this->session->userdata['newdata']['company'];
$companyName = $this->session->userdata('company');
```